Display brightness issue with HP Victus Laptop on Ubuntu 22.04 (JellyFish)
I have dual booted the system with Ubuntu 22.04 (Jellyfish) for my project purpose. When I boot with Ubuntu the display brightness is working in reverse manner. Increasing the brightness results in reduction of brightness and vice versa. Also the overall brightness compared to laptop booted on Windows is quite poor. Has anyone faced similar issue and found a way out for this issue? Reading and working due to low brightness has become a big challenge. Please suggest. I have already tried xbacklight and brightness controller but they did not work.
